# Django not rendering Crispy Form Fields from model

Tags: python, django, django-crispy-forms, django-bootstrap4

Hi I am a beginner to using django. In my project I am trying to construct a new project form to fill in information to store online. I'm using bootstrap4 as the default template pack in django_crispy_forms. I have been trying to render a form with the crispy tags/filter. I have another form I have used and had success in rendering the fields from a form. However this time I need to render the form from a model. The button and title render on the template but no matter what I try from other examples of modelforms I cant seem to make my fields render to the template like it should. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

my related code is as follows:
**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Project(models.Model):
    project_address = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from .models import Project

class projectForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = [
            'project_id',
        ]
```

**views.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect #added from enquiry views
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.conf import settings #added from enquiry views

from .models import Project
from .forms import projectForm

def projectinfo(request):
    form = projectForm(request.POST or None)
    context = {}
    template = 'projectinfo.html'
    return render(request,template,context)
```

**html**

```
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block content %}

            <form action="{% url 'projectinfo' %}" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
                {{ form|crispy }}               
                <input type="submit" value="Create New Project" class="btn btn-default" role="button" style="background-color: #007bff; color: #ffffff;"/>
            </form>

{% endblock %}
```

Settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    
    'projects’,
    'crispy_forms',
    
]
```

[Screenshot of button with un-rendered form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3vsgH.png)

Comment: Hello, you will help yourself, and anyone trying to answer this by making a minimal reproducing case - that is, removing as much code as you can while still reproducing the issue. Try seeing how much you can take away and still see this behaviour.

Comment: Hi Danny, thanks for your simple suggestion, that makes alot of sense and makes it easier to read and debugging. I got a bit ahead of myself with making other modules work in my app. I have minimised the code and edited above and I still have the same issue unfortunately.

Comment: Try binary chop the list of fields - to see if any of them is the cause. If it can be reproduced with only 1 field, that certainly reduces the problem scope.

Comment: Still no luck with just one field unfortunately...

Comment: Is crispy forms in the installed apps in settings?

Comment: It sure is. Have added part of the settings.py to the attached code above.

Comment: Which of those applications are yours?

Comment: 'projects’, is the app with the model form issue. 'crispy_forms',  is for the forms that aren’t appearing and 'colorful', is for a drop down color field to assign to projects. Allauth apps are for the login And the others Django requires.

Comment: I have tried renaming the models.py field name,I have also tried starting a new django project with just projects and crispy forms as the only user installed apps.However I still get the same issue of only the button appearing with no form fields rendered from models.py. So I don't believe it is bug related to other installed apps..I am a bit lost as what to try next..I have got form fields showing in another app based off information within the forms.py but trying to render form fields from the models.py information doesn't seem to work.Does anyone have any suggestions of what to try next?

Comment: Hi! In my project same issue...also in minimal-project the TextField is not rendered. Any hints?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it by adding the following template-info in the settings.py:

```
CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap4'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the form in the context:

```
def projectinfo(request):
    form = projectForm(request.POST or None)
    context = {
        'form': form
    }
    template = 'projectinfo.html'
    return render(request,template,context)
```